# Unable to get kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, kubernetes-dashboard

I've installad a new cluster (version 1.13.5 of kubectl kubelet kubeadm), then I've installed flannel and add a worker node.
Now I'm trying to add kubernetes dashboard to my cluster but after i run

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

I've this situation

```
kubernetes-dashboard-****   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          8s
```

Then if I get the log i can see this

```
 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver...
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: can you curl to you api server? `curl -v $(kubectl describe pod kube-apiserver-master -n kube-system | grep IP:|awk '{print $2}'):6443`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was on the worker, when I put the dashboard on master the pod starts. 
Maybe the kube dashboard has to be installed on the master or there is something wrong with flannel and the master-node communication.

Answer (score 0):

Check api-server pod is running or not and KubeDNS is working fine or not.

Comment: the api-server pod is running, how can i check for kubedns?

Comment: Check by pinging any pod with its name.

Comment: I've coredns pods and they are running too

Comment: please describe bothe API and Dashboard pod and share the same